# How to apply css and elemental styles to a ASP.net MVC 3 Web Application

Tags: html, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc

How to apply css and elemental styles to a ASP.net MVC 3 Web Application.here am posting my current project view code to Explain my problem.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "FranchIndex";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMaster.cshtml";
}

<h2>FranchIndex</h2>

<div class="login-wrap">
            <div class="login-head">
                <h3>Franchise Login</h3>
            </div>
            <form action="#" method="get">
                <div class="login-form">
                    <ul>
                        <li><i class="icon-user"></i><input type="text" class="login-user-input" @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.UserName)></li>
                        <li><i class="icon-key"></i><input type="password" class="login-pass-input" @Html.TextBoxFor(Model=>Model.Password)></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="login-action">
                    <button type="submit" class="backend-login-btn btn btn-block btn-large btn-inverse">Login</button>
                    <ul class="login-initial clearfix">
                        <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></li>
                        <li class="pull-right"><span class="rem-check"><input type="checkbox" checked></span>Remember Me</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </form>
            @*<h5>If You are a Franchise,Please @Html.ActionLink("Login Here", "FranchIndex", "Login") </h5> *@
        </div>
```

Comment: your question is not clear to us. what actually you are trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### in _LayoutMaster.cshtml include:

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/common")
```

#### and in App_Start/bundleConfig.css

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        // Shared Styling
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/common").Include(
                        "~/Css/Common.css",
                        "~/Css/jqueryui.css",
                        "~/Css/chosen.css"
                    ));
    }
}
```

or whatever combination of your individual style CSS files you have.

#### finally in global.asax:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
 {
     BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
 }
```

Comment: Where i have to include in _LayoutMaster.cshtml

Comment: Exactly where you would in a standard HTML page - styles typically go in the <head> element